# dplyr Arrange verb won't work on character class, only works on factors

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(PN = c("41681", "16588", "34881", 
"36917", "33116", "68447"), `2017-10` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2017-11` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2017-12` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2018-01` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2018-02` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2018-03` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2018-04` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Status = c("OK", "NOK", "OK", "NOK", "OK", 
"OK")), .Names = c("PN", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", 
"2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "Status"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The `Status` column in the `df` data frame above was generated with the following apply function:

```
mutate(
  Status = 
    ifelse(
      (apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & 
        (.[, 8] > 0), 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
      )
)
```

If I `%>%` pipe an `arrange(Status)` directly after the code chunk above I get the following error.

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :    Argument 1 is of unsupported
>   type matrix

If I run all my code without the `arrange(Status)` the code executes fine and turns into the reproducible chunk I setup at the beginning of this post - via `dput(df)`

The `Status` column is of type character, but if I factor it prior to running the `arrange(Status)` command the error shown above goes away.

I've never had an issue with the `arrange()` verb before on character classes. Why am I forced to factor my Status column to make the error go away? Is it something to do with my use of the apply command? That's the only new thing I've done in my 'programming' this time around.

Comment: `arrange` works just fine for me with your example data. My guess is that your actual data differs slightly from what you've provided here, most likely in that if you aren't careful with using `apply` in that mutate you could end up creating a column of character matrices.

Comment: I too, have been having this issue often since 3.4.4 updates. I've not been able pin-point the cause either.

Comment: @joran you are correct. If I use my reproducible data above the issue does not happen. If I use my *actual* df the error occurs. I too suspect it has something to do with `apply()`.

Comment: @akrun there were `NA` in my data but I replaced them earlier in my analysis with the following `mutate(n = parse_integer(str_replace_na(n, replacement = 0)))`

Comment: In that case, as joran said it is a column of matrix creation which you can change it to `vector` with `as.vector` wrapping on the `apply`.  Anyway, I would use `tidyverse` approaches instead of `apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier in my analysis I had to replace `NA` with `0` and this is what I did:

`mutate(n = parse_integer(str_replace_na(n, replacement = 0)))`

Apparently I ended up creating a column of character matrices, maybe with this apply command, maybe with the stringR command above, not sure which:

```
mutate(
  Status = 
    ifelse(
      (apply(.[, 2:7], 1, sum) > 0) & 
        (.[, 8] > 0), 
      "NOK", 
      "OK"
      )
)
```

As pointed out by @joran and @akrun the following fixed the issue:

`mutate(Status = as.vector(Status))`

Comment: I would use `rowSums` which is vectorised `df %>% mutate(Status = case_when(rowSums(.[2:7])> 0  & .[[8]] > 0 ~ "NOK", TRUE ~ "OK")` and it should give a single column instead of matrix column